# Residual constraints with reification in clpfd

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I defined reified variants of the 
[clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) constraints `(#<)/2`, `(#=<)/2`, `(#>=)/2` and `(#>)/2`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

ltA(X,Y,Truth)  :- X #<  Y #<==> B, bool01_truth(B,Truth).
ltB(X,Y, true)  :- X #<  Y.
ltB(X,Y,false)  :- X #>= Y.

lteA(X,Y,Truth) :- X #=< Y #<==> B, bool01_truth(B,Truth).
lteB(X,Y, true) :- X #=< Y.
lteB(X,Y,false) :- X #>  Y.

gteA(X,Y,Truth) :- X #>= Y #<==> B, bool01_truth(B,Truth).
gteB(X,Y, true) :- X #>= Y.
gteB(X,Y,false) :- X #<  Y.

gtA(X,Y,Truth)  :- X #>  Y #<==> B, bool01_truth(B,Truth).
gtB(X,Y, true)  :- X #>  Y.
gtB(X,Y,false)  :- X #=< Y.
```

Of course, `ltA/3` and `ltB/3` are **logically equivalent**, as are
`lteA/3` and `lteB/3`, `gteA/3` and `gteB/3`, and `gtA/3` and `gtB/3`.

The answers I get using these predicates, however, differ regarding size and readability. I ran the following queries with SWI-Prolog 7.1.37:

**Good news, first!**

```
?- lteA(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = false, Y#=<X+ -1 ;
Truth = true,  Y#>=X.
?- lteB(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = true,  Y#>=X ;
Truth = false, Y#=<X+ -1.

?- gteA(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = false, X#=<Y+ -1 ;
Truth = true,  X#>=Y.
?- gteB(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = true,  X#>=Y ;
Truth = false, X#=<Y+ -1.
```

**Ok!** But what about the other two?

```
?- ltA(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = false, X+1#=_G968, Y#=<_G968+ -1 ;
Truth = true,  X+1#=_G912, Y#>=_G912.
?- ltB(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = true,  X#=<Y+ -1 ;
Truth = false, X#>=Y.

?- gtA(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = false, X#=<_G1301+ -1, Y+1#=_G1301 ;
Truth = true,  X#>=_G1243,     Y+1#=_G1243.
?- gtB(X,Y,Truth).
Truth = true,  Y#=<X+ -1 ;
Truth = false, Y#>=X.
```

**Not quite!**

How do I get compact answers with `ltA/3` and `gtA/3`---just like with `lteA/3` and `gteA/3`?

Comment: I'd say: Don't worry. Rather measure performance on actual problems to produce feedback for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

It runs counter the basic idea of CLP(FD) to have compact
answers. Since CLP(FD) usually doesn't do gauss elimination and
similar things. Its not like a Computer Algebra System (CAS).

In CLP(FD), you basically model your problem by entering
inequations, and the system is allowed to do nothing with this
inequations as long as you don't call [labeling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=labeling/2).

Some CLP(FD) realizations already check consistency to some 
degree when entering inequations and/or already do simplifications 
and propagations. But this isnt mandatory.

In your example you have E #= X where E is an expression and
X is a variable. There is no guarantee that occurences
of X are replaced by E when entering a model.

Usually this is not done in CLP(FD), since it would blow 
up the entered model. You can directly test that this
is not simplified:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.4)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.
?- A#=X+1, Y#=<A+ -1.
Y#=<A+ -1,
X+1#=A.
```

The same also happens in Jekejeke Prolog. The CLP(FD) of
Jekejeke Prolog is open source [here](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/15_min/02_reference/finite/package.jsp). Refification itself
is planned but not yet implemented:

```
Jekejeke Prolog, Runtime Library 1.0.7
(c) 1985-2015, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland
?- use_module(library(finite/clpfd)).
% 11 consults and 0 unloads in 513 ms.
Yes
?- A#=X+1, Y#=<A+ -1.
A #= 1+X,
-1+A #>= Y
```

Typicall an equation E #= X only leads to substitutions when
E is also a variable or constant. This might explain why your 
examples look different from case to case.

Here you see SWI-Prolog simplifying A #= X. I just modified
the above example slightly so that E is a variable:

```
?- A#=X, Y#=<A+ -1.
A = X,
Y#=<X+ -1.
```

And here you see Jekejeke Prolog doing it (Todo bug fix: I 
guess I need to reorder the rules a little bit, so that it 
gives A = X and not X = A as here):

```
?- A#=X, Y#=<A+ -1.
X = A,
-1+A #>= Y
```

The case of E #= X where E is a constant and where this
value is propagated is called forward checking. This is the
minimum requirement a CLP(FD) must be able to do, otherwise
labeling would not work.

But already the case of E #= X where E is a variable a
propagation isn't mandatory. But the testing above shows
that many CLP(FD) do it. Propagating variables leads to 
union find algorithms and the like.

Bye